# difference between putting product in parameters vs returning value

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I am solving a algorithm question on leetcode with top-down DP. My first implementation put the product i am calculating in the parameters and returned it when base case is hit. However, this gives the wrong answer. When i change my code to instead return the product as a return value, it works. I'm struggling to understand why this is the case. I don't see what's wrong with my original implementation. Here's the ORIGINAL wrong implementation:

```
class Solution:
    def integerBreak(self, n: int) -> int:
        dp = {}

        def helper(total, prod):
            print(total, prod)
            if total == n:
                return prod
            elif total in dp:
                return dp[total]
            else:
                ans = 0
                for j in range(1, n-total+1):
                    if total == 0 and j == n:
                        continue
                    ans = max(helper(total+j, prod * j), ans)
                dp[total] = ans
                return ans
        
        return helper(0, 1)
```

and here is the CORRECT implementation:

```
class Solution:
    def integerBreak(self, n: int) -> int:
        dp = {}
        def helper(total):
            if total == n:
                return 1
            elif total in dp:
                return dp[total]
            else:
                ans = 0
                for j in range(1, n-total+1):
                    if total == 0 and j == n:
                        continue
                    ans = max(helper(total+j) * j, ans)
                dp[total] = ans
                return ans
        
        return helper(0)
```

The original implementation is wrong. I don't see why putting the product in the parameters makes it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On the line `ans = max(helper(total+j, prod * j), ans)` you should fix like this `ans = max(helper(total+j, prod) * j, ans)`

Comment: but i am storing the product in the 2nd parameter so I shouldnt have to multiply the return result again by j i think?

Comment: If you do that, it's just right with the case `total == n`, but with the case `total in dp` do not.